# QDir::rename() for 2 different partitions

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I see that `QDir` has problem with renaming files/dirs between 2 partitions.

As a solution I use `QProcess` and execute `mv`, which works fine, but it's a very ugly and I don't like it. Plus I will have to provide separate implementation for Windows and Mac (the latter one will hopefully be the same as for Linux).

Is there a better solution?

Comment: AFAIK there's no ready-made method, you have to implement a recursive directory copy and remove.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I thought I was fast enough to delete my comment before anyone sees it ;) I just saw that "not a directory" part just after I pasted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously said, you need to do a recursive copy. [Here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/source/86ca234004c0523f6abee5ef5796f55aa640e805:src/app/main.cpp#L165-190) is a good example.